# Any reason my NodeJs App shows up in terminal but doesn't connect to database through url?

Tags: node.js, express, namecheap

I'm currently trying to get my subdomain site online. Locally the site works, as well as the db, however, online, the site works but doesn't connect to the db. I'm using shared hosting provided by Namecheap and using the NodeJS App setup in cPanel. I can connect to the terminal and db via the terminal but not the URL. I'm not sure if it is a problem with code, port issue, or something else. I'm not getting an errors either. The site simply won't connect to the database.

I'm new to Node and Express, back-end in general, so much of the code is based on tutorials I followed using the Express docs. Locally, the sign up form would add a user to the db and return to the homepage, albeit slowly. On the server, it seems to require a new page, but never adds a user to the db. Below is my script:

```
var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    var path = require('path');
    const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
    const port = 3000;
    
    app.listen(port, hostname, () => {
        console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
    });
    
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + "/public")));
    
    app.get('/index.html', function (req, res, next) {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
        console.log("got index page");
    });
    
    app.use(express.urlencoded({
        extended: true
    }))
    
    app.get('/signup.html', function (req, res, next) {
        console.log("got signup page");
    });
    
    var mysql = require('mysql');
    var con = mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'localhost',
        user: '******',
        password: '******',
        database: '*******'
    });
    
    con.connect(function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("Connected to db");
    });
    
    
        app.post('self', (request, response) => {
            const username = request.body.username
            const password = request.body.password
            const email = request.body.email
            const gender = request.body.gender
    console.log(email);
    console.log(username);
    console.log(password);
      
            var sql = "INSERT INTO `accounts` (username, password, email, gender) VALUES ('" + username + "', '" + password + "', '" + email +"', '"+gender+"')";
            
        con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log("1 record inserted");
          
        });
         return request.redirect("/https://matcher.withaliquid.com/");
         });
    
    function getHomePage() {
        app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));
        app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
    });
    }
```

Comment: When it finally connects succesfully, be the first to read what the SQL injection is and why your code should be modified to prevent it!

Comment: Will definitely be adding validation to the input and sanitization once it's running. Thanks for the reminder.